# Leave iFrame On Mobile Detection?

Tags: facebook, iframe, mobile, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-canvas

Im working on a Facebook Canvas app, where people can share and like etc etc.   The problem I have is that most of the content is Flash and I dont want mobile users being directed to these pages.

I want to redirect them to a static page else where with mobile layout when they click on a link on from their facebook feed.  I dont want this page to be wrapped in the Facebook iframe.

I only want to do this for 1 or 2 pages, not the whole site.

Editing the Facebook application settings is a last resort (im a contractor and it will be hard to edit this)

Im hoping there is some method or header I can return that will not load the page in the facebook iframe.

Im using ASP MVC3 with the Facebook SDK library.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide a Mobile Web URL for exactly this purpose. With a Mobile Web URL, all traffic from feed posts on mobile will be redirected to the Mobile Web version of your app. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/ for more info.